# Ubuntu detects external hdmi screen and TV says its connected but nothing appears on tv screen

Tags: 14.04, hdmi

I have a HP G60 and a Sony Bravia KDL-32EX525, its almost unbeliavable that my hdmi isnt working because all the devices detect it but it doesnt show on screen. Im using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and im kinda newbie

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in Ubuntu Studio 14.04 LTS, running kernel version 3.13.0-43. I added an HDMI display (no sound capability) to my desktop as an addition to my older DVI monitor. Attempting to add the new screen from boot/power-on caused a system freeze. Attempts to add the HDMI display after boot via the Display applet under Settings Manager prompted a scrambled screen and system or X crashed (couldn't tell which one, screen unresponsive to anything but hard power cycle).

Booting to an earlier kernel version -in this case 3.13.0-40- resolved the issue (you can boot to prior kernels under the Advanced options in the Grub boot menu).

Interestingly, I found a strikingly similar issue with kernel 3.17.3 (Kernel Bug Tracker – Bug 88481) that had the exact same error message I had been getting from DMESG: BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffec2000000900. This seems to have possibly been brought on by commit ffe0245532b98efc4bc0e06f29c51d3f0e471152 in at least the case of the later kernel version.

References:

- Bug 88481 - Kernel oops leaves system without graphical output [radeon]
- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88481

HTH.